# How to avoid destruction in Class

Tags: c++, oop

I have a question that how i can avoid the destruction in class.
I have the sample code C++ here:

```
class Array {
    int *p;
    int n;
public:
    Array(int n_ = 0) {
        p = new int[n_];
    }
    ~Array(void) { 
        cout << "Deleted" << endl; delete []p;
    }
    friend Array operator+(Array A, Array B)        // the amount of elements A and B are the same
    {
        Array S(A.n);
        for(int i=0; i < A.n; i++)
            S.p[i] = A.p[i] + B.p[i];
        return S;     // object S has been destroyed before returned.
    }
};
```

In here, when the object has got the value and return. But object S have been destroyed by destruction before returned. Can anyone help me to avoid the destruction or some way for the object S can be returned to main. Thanks

Comment: Provide a copy constructor, so that the returned copy of `S` (which is what gets returned) is valid.

Answer (score 2):

You can either define a move and/or a copy constructor (if it is not implicitly defined) and the value will be moved/copied before its destruction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but If i use the copy constructor way, it will waste time for copy. Because if we apply it for n = 1000, it will spend O(1000), i don't want waste the time for copy

Comment: Then you can use move semantics to avoid the copy, which will be way faster

Comment: If you look at my answer, compiler adopts another optimization, before the move semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a copy ctor, than it will turn out that your compiler never call it, due to NRVO (named Return Value Optimization).

Read this wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

With C++11 o C++14, you can use the move semantics, a general technique to move expensive objects.

Comment: Yes, i think so. But in the scenario, i have many elements in the object, i will waste much time for doing the copy for object.

Comment: This is t really a move-only class though. I found that at least with gcc, RVO is still used if you have a move constructor but not a copy constructor. However, as soon as you put std::move on the return line the standard requires the move constructor to be run

Comment: Can you write down for me. I wrote it  return std::move(S); But it  was also destroyed.